# Setting a group container height to 0 does not hide his children

Tags: apache-flex

I need to resize a `Group` using `myGroup.height = 0`.
And it works, but myGroup's children are still visible, I do not know why...
Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Damn, i did look after the answer for 4 hours, and it was so easy...

To hide the content of a group container when setting the height to 0,
set `clipAndEnableScrolling = true;`

Indeed, the doc says :

*If true, specifies to clip the children to the boundaries of the viewport. If false, the container children extend past the container boundaries, regardless of the size specification of the component.*

Comment: You can accept your own answer. That way people coming by will instantly see that there is a correct answer to this question.

Comment: Right. Forgot about that again.